# Proliant DL360 G7 stuck on POST, no video, no beeps, front LED green

Tags: hp-proliant, bios, ilo

I am new to servers, so I am not sure what to do next. I have an HP proliant DL360 G7 with a HP P2000 hooked to it using HBA cards. I have Unraid installed on a USB and I was playing around with Unraid docker containers trying to make my own. This server has been running for about a month now with no issues. However I suddenly could no longer access unraid, shares, or even ping it.

I reset server and was unable to get any video or BIOS beeps. The health LED is solid green and shows no issues. I did research and found out about iLO, but I didn't know the iLO password, so I disabled the security(Switch on motherboard). I was then able to get into the iLO.

Under the iLO event logs the server seems to be continually resetting.

[Event Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZuNb.png)

When I go to iLO Server Power, it says "Server may be at POST. System Power Restore Settings can not be set during POST."

I have disconnected the Unraid USB and the HBA connections. I still cannot get it to show any video or progress in any way. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit: more information I found I could place /dromstuf.htm after my url and I got POST Debug Data. [Post Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeBXE.png)

**UPDATE FIX ACTION:**
Took all RAM out. I followed HP document at https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docLocale=en_US&docId=c02208506
for reinserting RAM two sticks to start. (2CPUs - Minimum Ram) That was able to get the POST to work and display come back on. I continued to follow the above document installing two RAM sticks and booting. Ran Memory check on each two sticks. Eventually I was able to insert all 18 sticks.  Found no issues, no idea why it shut off or what caused it. My guess was that one stick of the 18 had to be reseated or moved to another slot.

Comment: As silly as it sounds, when I can't get a machine to boot I disconnect all power, remove the cover, pull memory sticks out and re-seat them. Make sure CPU fans spin freely, pull out add on cards such as NIC & Video and re-seat them. Double check cables for drives are firmly attached etc. I have even pulled out CMOS batteries and done a board reset. On occasions this has worked for me.

Comment: Removed all RAM and SAS HBA cards, cleared NVRAM, reinstalled all RAM. Still not getting POST, BIOS, or display.

Comment: Do you have a motherboard tester by any chance? Have you recently installed any new hardware, drives etc? It's a tough one to diagnose at the best of times. :(

Comment: No motherboard tester. No new hardware or drives in the last 3 weeks. Everything was running fine until tonight when I was messing around with docker on Unraid.

Are you talking about a motherboard tester like this: Kingwin PC Computer Motherboard Analyzer Kit (amazon 9.99) or something different?

Comment: Yes, in fact it looks a lot like I used to have years ago. A board tester will read POST codes and tell you where it's stopping. With the code you can find out at what point it either stops or fails POST. From memory if it shows 255 on power up then the board is cactus. But it's been 15 years since I used one.

Comment: just looked at my motherboard and it only has PCIe x8 slots, so the one I linked earlier wont work.

Comment: I'm sure there is one somewhere. I didn't think of the slot types before, but still worth having if they are cheap enough.